# How to use radio button in html and javascript to insert into the database in CN1

Tags: codenameone

I was trying to get the values of radio button in html page  when checked and insert it into the sqlite database and mysql. This is my full code below:

```
Form hi = new Form("Hi World");


final WebBrowser b = new WebBrowser(){
 @Override
 public void onLoad(String url) {
    // Placed on onLoad because we need to wait for page 
    // to load to interact with it.

    BrowserComponent c = (BrowserComponent)this.getInternal();

    // Create a Javascript context for this BrowserComponent
    JavascriptContext ctx = new JavascriptContext(c);


 JSObject window = (JSObject)ctx.get("window");   

    window.set("addAsync", new JSFunction(){

        public void apply(JSObject self, final Object[] args) {
            String a = (String)args[0];
           // Double b = (Double)args[1];


           System.out.println("Value picked is "+a);


            JSObject callback = (JSObject)args[1];


            callback.call(new Object[]{new String(a)});


            System.out.println("ok Good");
        }

    });


   } 
};



  b.setPage( "<html lang=\"en\">\n" +
   " <head>\n" +
    " <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n" +
    " <script>\n" +
"function test() {"+
   " var radios = document.getElementsByName('radiotest');"+
 " var found = 1;"+
 "  for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) { "  +
  "  if (radios[i].checked) {"+
  // "   document.getElementById('input3').setAttribute('value',       radios[i].value); "  +   

    "    alert(radios[i].value);"+

     "   found = 0;"+
     "   break;"+
    "  }"+
    "}"+
   " if(found == 1)"+
  "  {"+
  "  alert('Please Select Radio');"+
   " }  "+
  "}"+      


   // + \n" +
  " var radios = document.getElementsByName('radiotest')"+
       " document.addEventListener('click', function(){\n" +
   " var found = 1;"+ 
   "  for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) { "  +
  "  if (radios[i].checked) {"+
    // "   document.getElementById('input3').setAttribute('value',       radios[i].value); "  +   

       "    alert(radios[i].value);"+

        "   found = 0;"+
        "   break;"+
     "  }"+
          "}"+
       " if(found == 1)"+
       "  {"+
     "  alert('Please Select Radio');"+
         " }  "+      


"       a = document.getElementById('val1').value ;\n" +
"       b = document.getElementById('val2').value\n" +
"       window.addAsync(a, b, function(result){\n" +
"       document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;\n" +
"        });\n" +
"    }, true);  "
         + ""      +

" </script>\n" +
" </head>\n" +
" <body >\n" +
    "   <table border='0' cellspacing = '15'>"+
              "  <thead>"+

      "          </thead>"+
            "    <tbody>"+
               "     <tr>"+

                "  <td><font size = '3'> <b>A </font></b><input type='radio' name='radiotest'  id='val1' onclick='test()' value='1'  style='border: none;'> value1</input>"+
"</td>"+
                "    </tr>"+
                  "  <tr>"+
                      "  <td><font size = '3'> <b> B</font></b><input type='radio' name='radiotest' id='val2' onclick='test()' value='2' style='border: none;'> value2</input>"+
"</td>"+            " </tr>"+
                       "  <tr>"+
                       " <td> <font size = '3'> <b>C </font></b><input type='radio' name='radiotest' id='val3' onclick='test()' value='3'style='border: none;'> value3</input>"+
              "        </tr>"+
                         "<tr>"+
                         " <td> <font size = '3'> <b>D </font></b> <input type='radio' name='radiotest'id='val4' onclick='test()' value='4'style='border: none;'> value4</input>"+
                  "  </tr>"+
                "</tbody>"+
            "</table>"+       
           "<span id=\"result\"></span>"+

" </body>\n" +
"</html>", null);


hi.setLayout(new BorderLayout());



hi.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
hi.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, b);
hi.show();
```

The code above did not work for me. Pls help.

[image]
The problem am having now is to add actionListener to the radio button when checked by collecting its value and insert these values into the database accordingly.

**I have edited my code, With this I can get the value selected with javascript function with the code below. Now, How can I insert the values of the radio button into the database as I click on radio button.**

```
       Form hi = new Form("BrowserComponent", new BorderLayout());
BrowserComponent bc = new BrowserComponent();
bc.setPage( "<html lang=\"en\">\n" +
" <head>\n" +
" <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n" +

" </head>\n" +
" <body >\n" +
    "   <table border='0' cellspacing = '15'>"+
              "  <thead>"+

      "          </thead>"+
            "    <tbody>"+
               "     <tr>"+

                "  <td><font size = '3'> <b>A </font></b><input type='radio' name='radiotest' id = 'val1' onclick='test()'  value='1' style='border: none;'> value1</input>"+
"</td>"+
                "    </tr>"+
                  "  <tr>"+
                      "  <td><font size = '3'> <b> B</font></b><input type='radio' name='radiotest'id = 'val2' onclick='test()' value='2' style='border: none;'> val2</input>"+
"</td>"+
                        " </tr>"+
                       "  <tr>"+
                       " <td> <font size = '3'> <b>C </font></b><input type='radio' name='radiotest' onclick='test()' value='3'style='border: none;'> val3</input>"+


              "        </tr>"+
                         "<tr>"+
                         " <td> <font size = '3'> <b>D </font></b> <input type='radio' name='radiotest' onclick='test()' value='4'style='border: none;'> val4</input>"+

                  "  </tr>"+
                "</tbody>"+
            "</table>"+       





  " <script type='text/javascript'>" +

   //This javascript is perfect now.           
  "function test() {"+
   " var radios = document.getElementsByName('radiotest');"+
   " var found = 1;"+
  "  for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) { "  +
      "  if (radios[i].checked) {"+
      // "   document.getElementById('input3').setAttribute('value', radios[i].value); "  +   
           // "    instruction = document.getElementById('input3').value"  +
            //   "'"+option_code2+"'"+
        "    alert(radios[i].value);"+

         "   found = 0;"+
         "   break;"+
     "  }"+
   "}"+
   " if(found == 1)"+
  "  {"+
  "  alert('Please Select Radio');"+
   " }  "+
"}"+

      "</script>"+


" </body>\n" +
"</html>", null);
TextField tf = new TextField();
hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, bc).
add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, tf);
//bc.addWebEventListener("onLoad", (e) -> bc.execute("fnc('<p>Hello World</p>')"));



hi.show();
```

Comment: Why are you using HTML? This is **really** hard to debug as there are multiple places where this can fail.

Comment: I have questions that will come up from the database inform of subscript, superscript which can only be handled perfectly in HTML

Comment: The real problem am facing is to add EventListener to the radio button when checked. If I can add EventListener to the radio button when checked, I will call the value of radio button and insert it into the database.

Comment: Thanks for your response sir. I have edited the code, when radio button is clicked it will return the value of the radio button, but I can not call this value into TextField. Maybe I can add actionListener to the TextField when  values is passed into it. Sir you may check my edited code above. Thanks

Comment: I would parse the questions from the server using XMLParser and create a UI in Codename One. The communication between JavaScript/Codename One is possible but painful

Comment: pls is there any means to handle subscript and superscript in codename one without using HTML? If yes, pls suggest the solution for me. Thanks for your response sir

Comment: You can change the font sizes and padding which is effectively what subscript/superscript is

Comment: I still have the challenges of this subscript and superscript. Assuming I can add actionListener to the radio button in the BrowserComponent. HTML would have be the best to handle this.

Comment: I don't know why this code  window.addAsyn(a, b, function(result){
 document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
 });  is not working  in Browser.setPage(html, null). I would have get out of this mess,  and it works with browser.setUrl(jar:///myhtml.html) which can not solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your libraries are up to date, if the JavaScript bridge works correctly for `setURL` but fails for `setPage` it sounds like something we fixed in a recent update.